# interesting question about mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have following doubt.

Mean value theorem states for any continuous differential function $f$ over $(a,b)$,

There exists some $c$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$

My question is for any $d$, can we find an $i$ and $j$ such that

$f'(d)<=\frac{(f(i)-f(j))}{(i-j)}?$ Can we extend the argument to multi-variable function? Thanks

Comment: $f(x)=-x^3$, $d=0$.

Comment: You've misstated the MVT.